# css background-image doesn't work on IE?

Tags: html, css

This css style is working perfectly on all browsers when the site is on LOCALHOST.
but when I uploaded the site to a live server, It also works on all browsers except IE.

The background-image don't show.

```
.button {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
background:url(../images/button-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #3b3d3e;
border:1px solid #3b3d3e;
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
padding:1px 9px;
margin-right:7px;
border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
 }
```

NOTE: as you can see I use the color #3b3d3e with the background, and when the page loads I see this color for a part of a second, and then it disappears.

what is wrong with this?

Comment: try: `background: transparent url(../images/button-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #3b3d3e;`

Comment: delete catch files and all of browser temp files and try again.

Comment: and does it work properly on IE in localhost?

Comment: I tried clearing the cach and tried to use transparent but no hope to get it to work.  and YES it is working perfectly on IE on localhost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe background should be written out in this order:
background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image;
Maybe IE is the only browser that cares?

If that doesn't work maybe try adding each background value you need seperately:
background-color, background-position, background-size, background-repeat, background-origin, background-clip, background-attachment, and background-image.

Also as a side note you might want to try commenting out the last line in the css "behavior:url(js/PIE.htc)". I know sometimes these things like to conflict with other properties. I have never used PIE myself, but its worth a shot commenting out.

Comment: I tried:  background-image:url('../images/button-bg.gif');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-color:red; but this don't work, not even the red color. but when i remove the image and the repeat i can see the bg color

Answer (score 1):

Color first:

```
background: #3b3d3e url(../images/button-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
```

Comment: not working, still the style shows correct for a part of a second and then disappear...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `zoom:1` to .button

This triggers the hasLayout property on IE7.
Detailed explanation here: 
[On having Layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it fixed but still don't know what is the reason...
I removed the

```
 behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
```

from it, and it worked perfectly...

I'm pretty sure that the file PIE.htc is there but I don't know what is wrong.
anyone??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on my site yet, because the server has been down but it might be worth looking into Modernizr http://modernizr.com/

I had a hard time getting background images to show moving from local to my server, and what I ended up having to do was use the full path of the image.

If it is infact a browser confliction problem, this should help solve it.

Also, have you tried commenting out `behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);`?
This could be what's giving it fits.

When i put a background-image in my CSS, I type it like so:

```
background-image: url("path/to/image.img"); background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-color:#color;
```

I see you tried this, and I'm trying to think of several options, would working with the Z-index affect what you are trying to do?

Give Modernizr a look over

Answer (score 0):

It may be a relative path issue between localhost and server environment. See the detailed explanation on the CSS 3 PIE known issues page. 
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths

Was PIE working at all? — Were there rounded corners on the button on IE 7?

This may be helpful too. 
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index